# Snippet to replace accented vowel by vowel without tilde in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext-snippet

In the following snippet of LaTeX package (sublime text 3) every time I enter a: Space, . (dot), ?, *, #, Is replaced by "_" character in the part \label{sec:*****} and % section ***** (end). Also replaces capital letters to lowercase. Here the snippet:

```xml
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/\\\w+\{(.*?)\}|\\(.)|(\w+)|([^\w\\]+)/(?4:_:\L$1$2$3)/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sec</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>Section</description>
</snippet>
```

My question is: how can I change? the snippet to replace accented vowel by vowel without tilde, ie,
if I use the snippet the result is:

```
\section{acción además menú aquí acné} % (fold)
\label{sec:acción_además_menú_aquí_acné}

% section acción_además_menú_aquí_acné (end)
```

but I want to get the following:

```
\section{acción además menú aquí acné} % (fold)
\label{sec:accion_ademas_menu_aqui_acne}

% section accion_ademas_menu_aqui_acne (end)
```

Comment: This is not possible with a snippet - you'll need a plugin to do the replacement.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you, any suggestions of where I can start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by manually specifying the characters to find and what to replace them with. This is because ST unfortunately doesn't seem to support the [POSIX character equivalents](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#eq).

Using the following snippet:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/(?i:(á)|([éę])|(í)|(ó)|(ú)|(ń))|\\\w+\{(.*?)\}|\\(.)|(\w)|([^\w\\]+)/(?{10}_:\L$7$8(?1a:)(?2e:)(?3i:)(?4o:)(?5u:)(?6n:)$9)/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sec</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>Section</description>
</snippet>
```

typing `sec` <kbd>Tab</kbd> and typing/pasting in `acción además menú aquí acné ńę`, for example, will result in:

> ```
> \section{acción además menú aquí acné_ńę} % (fold)
> \label{sec:accion_ademas_menu_aqui_acne_ne}
>
> % section accion_ademas_menu_aqui_acne_ne (end)
> ```

For more information on the replacement format syntax, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html

Comment: Nice job, I didn't think regex could handle multiple possible substitutions like that.

Comment: Dear @keith-hall, I'm currently working with visual studio code. How could I make the same snippet for this editor? 
Thank you

Comment: @rral, not sure, I suggest asking a new question with the appropriate tags :)