# How to ignore accented letters when using the search function of Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When searching for text in Sublime Text, the search is sensitive to accented letters. This is not very practical when I want to find all matches regardless of the accents. Is there a setting for the search function that makes it ignore the accents?

Comment: Can you include an example of what you're searching for and what's not being found?

Comment: For example, searching for "sabado", (Saturday in Spanish). It will not find "sábado"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Sublime Text's Find feature does not support [Character Equivalence](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#eq), so there is no way to get it to ignore the accents.

[I explored this before in the context of snippets and replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784552/4473405), but for this use case, you could write a Python plugin to build the character equivalence for you and populate the Find panel appropriately.

You may find it is enough to just temporarily replace the whole file with it's [unidecoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729827/compare-2-strings-without-considering-accents-in-python) representation and search that.

Comment: Thanks! That's unfortunate. Lets hope that Sublime adds this option in future.